# Consistent Timeout on Specific Line of Code in C# Selenium Web Scraping App

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm building a web app to scrape news from another website. The website has over 1700 pages of news with 36 news items on each page. After fixing some bugs, my WebDriver started consistently timing out about 15 pages in on the exact same line. I've checked basic issues such as network connection and set reasonable waiting times for pageload and commandTimeout, but with no success.

The exception that is being thrown is `The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 120 seconds`. Until very recently I have tried to set it to 600 seconds along with the `pageload`, but to no success either.

The exception is being thrown on this specific line:

```
if (driver.Url.Contains(newsUrl))
```

Here is a section of my code where the exception is being thrown:

```
try {
  var currentUrl = driver.Url;
  if (currentUrl.Contains("Error404")) {
    driver.Navigate().Back();
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine(currentUrl);
    Console.WriteLine("In try-catch block to create the news");
    CreateTheNews(driver);
    driver.Navigate().Back();
    var random = new Random();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(1, 3));
    var PaginateDivExists = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.paginate")).Count > 0;
    if (!PaginateDivExists) {
      driver.Navigate().Back();
      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(1, 3));
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  var newsUrl = "https://www.dunavmost.com/novini/";

  while (true) {
    if (driver.Url.Contains(newsUrl)) {
      driver.Navigate().Back();
      Console.WriteLine("Went back because the URL contains newsUrl");
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine("BREAK!");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a significant delay _between_ page loads to check that the remote website isn't ignoring your connection because of rate limiting? The pattern of multiple request succeeding and then failing after about the same number of requests sounds like it could be a rate limit. See for example https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/rate-limiting-rules/

Comment: @IanMercer I have added a timeout of 1 minute after every page ( 36 news a page ) implicit wait and I have also added additional 2 minutes implicit wait every 5 pages. However it seems that the issue continues being exactly the same